# .NET Core 7, using a different assembly for authorization middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a project called `Modules.Authenticate.Core` which contains all the logic to configure authentication and authorization.

The Startup class contains this code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Modules.Authenticate"));
        });

        // Agrega autenticación
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

On the other hand, I have another project called `Modules.Personal.Core`. That project contains an api controller that should be authorized using the token provided by `Modules.Authenticate.Core`.

The token request works perfectly, however, when I use the `AuthorizeAttribute` in the api controller of `Modules.Personal.Core`, this exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint
> Modules.Personal.Core.Controllers.Api.PersonaController.Get
> (Modules.Personal.Core) contains authorization metadata, but a
> middleware was not found that supports authorization. Configure your
> application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() in the
> application startup code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and
> app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseAuthorization() must go
> between them.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingAuthMiddlewareException(Endpoint
> endpoint)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

`Modules.Personal.Core` has its own Startup class with this code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesPersonalContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Modules.Personal"));
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

I know that the `Configure` method is actually being called.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I use the AuthorizeAttribute in the api controller of
> Modules.Personal.Core, this exception is thrown. I know that the
> Configure method is actually being called. How can I do this?

Actully, based on your shared code and exception details it's been appeared that, your middleware causing the error or exception because, when you would use `app.UseAuthorization()` you would need to follow the middleware order accordingly instead it will ended up with the exception which you are getting now.

Solution:

In order to the call to `UseAuthorization` should appear between the calls to `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`. If the [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order) doesn't followed exactly then the authorization will not act and get failed.

We should follow below order:

[image]

Middleware Order:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        
    }
```

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Authorization middleware  configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0001?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-to-fix-violations) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0001?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-to-fix-violations)